# Bases and Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am working through the following notes:

http://www.win.tue.nl/~sterk/algebra3/hoofd.pdf

I have come across Proposition 2.4.7 on Page 21 which is given without proof. For completeness and clarity, I would like to prove it. I have managed to prove by contradiction that the given basis is linearly independent. However, I have been unable to make any progress with linear independence. I was thinking that induction on $m\ge n$ could be suitable, but cannot progess.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely this have been answered before.

The idea is to consider the minimal polynomial of $a$, $p(a)$ and remainder after division by it.

Assume $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$. Assume that $q(x)$ is such that $q(a)\neq0$. Then $(p,q)=1$. Therefore there exist polynomials $M(x),N(x)$ such that $p(x)M(x)+q(x)N(x)=1$. Therefore $q(a)N(a)=1$. This means that $q(a)$ has an inverse $N(a)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[a]$.

To check the dimension, consider remainders after division by $p(x)$.

If $q(a)\in\mathbb{Q}[a]$ then $q(a)=p(a)Q(a)+r(a)=r(a)$, where $Q(a),r(a)\in\mathbb{Q}[a]$ are polynomials in $a$ and $r$ has degree $<\deg(p)$. Therefore every element of $\mathbb{Q}[a]$ is a linear combination of $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$.